# Find all indexes of substrings in a string and respective limits with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a function that would return information on the position of substrings in a larger string with javascript. I don't know if something like this exists natively so I want to take my chances here.

For example, having the following input string:

`"dog elephant you me test another test what thesis"`

And if I have the following array:

`array("Dog", "test", "not this one", "what the heck", "thesis")`

What is the most efficient way to **indexOf** the position of all these elements in the input string? Having the function return an object with information like this:

- "Dog" - from 0 to 3
- "test" - from (where `test` begins) to (where it ends)
- "not this one" - null (not in the string)
- "what the heck" - null (not in the string)
- "thesis" - from (where `thesis` begins) to (where it ends)

Does anyone have any idea?
Tyvm!

Comment: A loop, `.indexOf()` and math (_"(where it ends)"_ = `index + length`)

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you're asking. You want a javascript function that takes in a string and an array of strings, then searches the string for each item in the array, then returns an object of their indexes or null? What should the format of the output object be? Should it be a dictionary? Two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is case-sensitive:

```js
var str = "dog elephant you me test another test what thesis";

var words = ["dog", "test", "not this one", "what the heck", "thesis"];

var indices = words.map(function (word) {
  var start = str.indexOf(word);
  if (start === -1) {
    return null;
  }
  return { word, start, end: start + word.length };
});

console.log(indices);
```

I can only guess what you want the result to look like. My solution returns an array of objects. The objects have a `word` property containing the word in question, a `start` property for the start index and a `end` property for the end index. If the word was not found, the object is replaced by `null`.

Comment: Perfect! I thought of something similar but wanted to make sure it was the most efficient. Thank you :)

Comment: Native for loops can be a bit more efficient, but `map` is clearer. I wonder if the one who gave me a downvote would explain the reason.